# Instantiate: what should happen at low level

Tags: php, c

I'm slowly reading PHP 7 source code, written in C. But I'm really curious about "instancing a class". In PHP, this happen writing `$myclassvar = new myclass()`.

What should this code exactly do in C? What type of var is `$myclass` ? Why should we `instantiate`a class? Should this mean call the constructor `__construct()` ? Can you please explain me what should this code refers to (detailed). Thanks

Comment: The correct term in instanciate, as in an instance of an object, in accordance with my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not have classes, but the closest thing in C is `malloc`ing structures on the heap. The PHP code `$myclassvar = new myclass()` is most similar to

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} pt;

pt *p = malloc(sizeof(pt));
```

Comment: Yes. I thought about struct as the real type of $myclass. So the PHP compiler should allocate space using malloc() and then call the construct?

Comment: Yes, the PHP compiler calls `malloc` during the constructor and `free` in the destructor.

Comment: Should PHP call malloc only on vars/functions that are called in __construct() and use realloc after, or malloc the entire class?

Comment: @Andrea it will malloc the entire class, for efficiency purposes, because reallocating can be computationally expensive, and you typically use all the fields anyway